# Extended GCD of two zero polynomials over finite field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

[Extended GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Polynomial_extended_Euclidean_algorithm) of two polynomials $a$ and $b$ results in two polynomials $s$ and $t$ so that $as + bt = \text{gcd}(a, b)$.

What convention makes most sense when both $a$ and $b$ are zero?

I found that SymPy [chooses](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/polys/galoistools.py#L1110) $(s, t, \text{gcd}) = (1, 0, 0)$ and this got me wondering why is it better than $(0, 0, 0)$ or some other values?

Comment: Looks like a random choice, just to return *something* that works. Clearly $s$ and $t$ are not uniquely determined when $a=b=0$.